# How to sort out/ extract positive and negative powers as list?

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, expression-construction

I have the following expression

```
expr = x1^d1 * x2^d2 * x3^d3;
```

where `d1,d2,d3` can contain negative values/expression i.e. in general these `d1,d2,d3` may not be numerical values. Say

```
d1 = 4 d;
d2 = -5 e;
d3 =  -6 d;
with assumption d, e are positive.
```

Question : **Is there any way to make two lists one containing positive exponent and other with negative exponent?**

My current try is to use `Exponent` for each one of these terms and test them for positive and negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = x1^d1*x2^d2*x3^d3;

exponents = 
 Cases[expr, x_^p_. :> p, 1] /. {d1 -> 4 d, d2 -> -5 e, d3 -> -6 d}

(* {4 d, -5 e, -6 d} *)

pos = Assuming[{d > 0, e > 0}, Select[exponents, Simplify[# > 0] &]]

(* {4 d} *)

neg = Assuming[{d > 0, e > 0}, Select[exponents, Simplify[# < 0] &]]

(* {-5 e, -6 d} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `` Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ `` with `` GeneralUtilities`SelectDiscard ``, `GroupBy`, `Cases`, `DeleteCases`, `Select` or `Pick` as follows:

```
expr = x1^d1*x2^d2*x3^d3
```

> ```
> x1^(4 d) x2^(-5 e) x3^(-6 d)
> ```

```
exponents = Exponent[expr, {x1, x2, x3}]
```

> ```
> {4 d, -5 e, -6 d}
> ```

```
{neg, pos} = GeneralUtilities`SelectDiscard[Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ] @ exponents

{neg, pos} = GroupBy[exponents, Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ] /@ {True, False}

{neg, pos} = Cases[#@_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ]@exponents & /@ 
   {Identity, Except}

{neg, pos} = DeleteCases[#@_?Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ] @ exponents & /@ 
   {Except, Identity}

{neg, pos} = Select[#@*Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ]@exponents & /@ 
   {Identity, Not}

{neg, pos} = Pick[exponents, 
    Internal`SyntacticNegativeQ /@ exponents, #] & /@ {True, False}
```

all give

> ```
>  {{-5 e, -6 d}, {4 d}}
> ```